# php site root fundamentals on local server and online servers

Tags: php, path, directory-structure, document-root

so after spending a lot of time in figuring out site root i have decided to ask this question

my site has the following directory structure:

```
includes     //(contains db and other includes files)
public_html  //(this is the web -appication)
```

what i want is the path to this dir that contains these two folders and not the path inside these folders.

so inside the includes dir i have a file called **initialize.php**:

```
 defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT',dirname(__FILE__));
```

this gives the following output on wamp:

```
  C:\wamp\www\Mysite\includes\
```

on the server i get:

```
/home/a4554444/includes
```

what i want is this:

```
  C:\wamp\www\MySite\
```

i want to remove the **\includes** folder which is being listed at the end so i can use the path to access the **public_html** folder and use it on other paths as well

how can i do that?

please also mention it this way the "correct" way of getting the site root. if not mention the correct way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you looking for something like:

```
define('serverpath', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/');
```